# Defining file_counts

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Re-implementation of the counts function that obtains a list of numbers from a
file. In the file, every single line will contain a single integer and nothing
else. The last character will be a newline.

filename :: a string indicating the name of a file in the current directory.

Return value: a dictionary of int as keys and # of occurrences as the values.

```
file_counts("file1.txt")   →  {100:3, 3:1, 9:2}

file_counts("file2.txt")   →  {1:1, 2:1, 3:1, 4:1, 5:1}
```

Test cases:

check that when file1.txt contains `"1\n1\n1\n2\n3\n3\n3\n3\n5\n"`, that `file_counts("file1.txt") == {1:3,2:1,3:4,5:1}`.

check that when file1.txt contains `"100\n100\n3\n100\n9\n9\n"`, that `file_counts("file1.txt") == {100:3, 3:1, 9:2}`.

Basically, the characters of the file will be printed on a new line the number of times they show up. So for 100:3, 100 would be printed 3 times.

*Background information:

```
def counts(xs):
    d = {}
    for item in xs:
         d[item] = xs.count(item)
    return d
```

This function counts the characters in the dictionary and returns the count of each character*

I am not sure how to implement this function. I have been trying multiple ways and this is the closest I have gotten to an answer. I am not sure what the missing piece/s is/are and would appreciate any help.

My code:

```
def file_counts(filename):
    dict = {}
    with open(filename) as file_counts:
         for line in file_counts:
```

I get stuck on what to do next. I try to do an edit of the count function but it was not successful.

I am new to this site so I am not positive on format, so feel free to edit the question for formatting and if more information is required please ask

Comment: I would recommend not using `dict` as a variable name - it will hide the `dict` type. Similarly, a variable with the same name as your function (e.g. `file_counts`) will likely cause you issues. You can implement `file_counts()` using `counts()`, turn the file into a list of `int`s and pass the resulting list to `counts()`. BTW, there is a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class in the standard `collections` module that does this for you.

Comment: @AChampion So file_count is just counting the dictionary in the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read in the whole document as a string with the `read` method. You will then have a string of values with `\n` characters in between each. You can reduce the string to a list of the values with the `split()` method. Finally, you can use the `collections.Counter` module to count the instances of each value.

```
import collections as c
def file_counts(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f: # use flag 'r' to just read the doc
         data = f.read()      # read in the data file as a single string
    data = data.strip()       # get rid of the last \n on the end
    data = data.split('\n')   # break up the string into a list of values 
    counted_data = c.Counter(data)
    return dict(counted_data)
```

Note that you should avoid using `dict` to name you dictionary. `dict` is a reserved word in python used to generate a dictionary from a object which maps to a dictionary (eg - a list of tuples).